# Flutter iOS : Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, flutter

Unable to build the Flutter iOS App.
**Still don't find clue to sort this issue.

Using Flutter 3.7.12 Xcode 14.2.
M1 Mac
After trying multiple workaround I don't find exact solution**

```
 ^~~~~~~~~~
               newUser
    2 warnings generated.
    In file included from
    /Users/sus/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/webengage_flutter-1.2.4/ios/Classes/WebEn
    gagePlugin.m:3:

            ^
    livhjpjdnrnhkjymr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CrashReporter.build/Debug-iphonesim
    ulator/CrashReporter iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PLCrashLogWriter.o unable to
    open object file: No such file or directory
    warning: (x86_64)
    /Users/shekhargupta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CrashReporter-akgtfajxycj
    livhjpjdnrnhkjymr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CrashReporter.build/Debug-iphonesim
    ulator/CrashReporter iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PLCrashAsync.o unable to
    open object file: No such file or directory
    warning: (x86_64)
    /Users/shekhargupta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CrashReporter-akgtfajxycj
    livhjpjdnrnhkjymr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CrashReporter.build/Debug-iphonesim
    ulator/CrashReporter iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PLCrashLogWriterEncoding.o
    unable to open object file: No such file or directory
    warning: (x86_64)
    /Users/shekhargupta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CrashReporter-akgtfajxycj
    livhjpjdnrnhkjymr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CrashReporter.build/Debug-iphonesim
    ulator/CrashReporter iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PLCrashReporter.o unable to
    open object file: No such file or directory
    warning: (x86_64)
    /Users/shekhargupta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CrashReporter-akgtfajxycj
    livhjpjdnrnhkjymr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CrashReporter.build/Debug-iphonesim
    ulator/CrashReporter
    iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PLCrashReport-11249c1192c18cc76f5d36d106873855.o
    unable to open object file: No such file or directory
    warning: (x86_64)
    /Users/shekhargupta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CrashReporter-akgtfajxycj
    livhjpjdnrnhkjymr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CrashReporter.build/Debug-iphonesim
    ulator/CrashReporter iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PLCrashReportSystemInfo.o
    unable to open object file: No such file or directory
    warning: (x86_64)
    /Users/shekhargupta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CrashReporter-akgtfajxycj
    livhjpjdnrnhkjymr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CrashReporter.build/Debug-iphonesim
    ulator/CrashReporter
    iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PLCrashReportApplicationInfo.o unable to open
    object file: No such file or directory
    warning: (x86_64)
  

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/0z/nxwbg1xj73q7yjq_8_y4bq300000gp/T/flutter_tools.OE7sso/flutter_io
        s_build_temp_dir95kwpx/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.
```

Things that I have tried
1.flutter clean
2.Installing latestpods
3.check mark done on build phase->based on dependency analysis

tried workaround but non of them helps, tried with multiple Xcode version also(14.1,14.0)

Error log : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1io2e4lvr89i6tnnHmv6gjjQov7fXTSsJ/view?usp=share_link

Comment: can you post more error logs?  i can't find any errors on your posted logs

Comment: @ZTChen attached error log in drive link

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause due to space in folder name its not building.i have test in normal folder its working fine

test test **not works**

test **works**

Really a strange issue

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. `flutter clean`
2. `cd ios` ==> `pod deintegrate`
3. `pod cache clean --all`
4. `cd ..` ==> `flutter pub get`
5. `cd ios` ==> `pod install`
6. then build or archive

maybe it helps

Comment: will try in affected folders

Comment: it does not works actually the answer I have posted works